Next.js connect to Google Cloud PostgreSQL gives error "Module not found: Can't resolve 'oracledb'", but I am not using Oracle at all
I trying to create an application in Next.js with typescript that will connect to Google Cloud PostgreSQL database. I get an error Module not found: Can't resolve 'oracledb'. The
code is for connecting to a PostgreSQL database using Knex and the Google Cloud SQL Connector, so there should be no need for the oracledb module.
api/signup/route.ts
I have created a route that connects to the database called api/signup/route.ts.
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";


import connectWithConnector from '@/connect-connector';


export async function POST(request: Request){
    const json = await request.json();

    try {
        // Initialize the Knex connection
        const knex = await connectWithConnector({
          // Additional configuration options can go here
          pool: { min: 0, max: 7 }
        });
    
        // Perform a simple query
        const result = await knex.raw('SELECT NOW()');
        console.log('Current Timestamp:', result.rows[0]);
    
        // Close the connection
        await knex.destroy();
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting to the database:', error);
      }
      
    return NextResponse.json({ msg: "registration success" }, { status: 201 });
}

types/declarations.d.ts
I needed to declare google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector as a module.
// types/declarations.d.ts
declare module '@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector' {
  interface ConnectorOptions {
    instanceConnectionName: string;
    ipType?: 'PRIVATE' | 'PUBLIC';
  }

  interface ClientOptions {
    user?: string;
    password?: string;
    database?: string;
    [key: string]: any;
  }

  class Connector {
    getOptions(options: ConnectorOptions): Promise<ClientOptions>;
  }
}
  

.env.local
The env.local holds variables for connecting to the database.
INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME="project:europe-north1:dbname"
DB_USER="myuser"
DB_PASS="mypassword"
DB_NAME="postgres"
PRIVATE_IP="false" # or "true" if using private IP

connect-connector.ts
Next I have the connect-connector.ts which makes the connection to the database.
import knex, { Knex } from 'knex';
import { Connector } from '@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector';

type IpType = 'PRIVATE' | 'PUBLIC';

const getIpType = (): IpType =>
  process.env.PRIVATE_IP === '1' || process.env.PRIVATE_IP === 'true'
    ? 'PRIVATE'
    : 'PUBLIC';

interface KnexConfig {
  [key: string]: any;
}

const connectWithConnector = async (config?: KnexConfig): Promise<Knex> => {
  const connector = new Connector();
  const clientOpts = await connector.getOptions({
    instanceConnectionName: process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME as string,
    ipType: getIpType(),
  });

  const dbConfig: Knex.Config = {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: {
      ...clientOpts,
      user: process.env.DB_USER as string,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS as string,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME as string,
    },
    ...config,
  };

  return knex(dbConfig);
};

export default connectWithConnector;

package.json

I have installed @google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector, bcrypt, jose, knex, pg.
I have dev dependencies @faker-js/faker, @types/bcrypt, @types/node, @types/pg.


{
  "name": "vv-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/cloud-sql-connector": "^1.3.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "jose": "^5.6.3",
    "knex": "^3.1.0",
    "next": "14.2.4",
    "pg": "^8.12.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@faker-js/faker": "^8.4.1",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.10",
    "@types/pg": "^8.11.6",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}


tsconfig.json
I also added the declarations into tsconfig.json: "typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"]
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["./types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts", "connect-connector.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

My Error Message: Module not found: Can't resolve 'oracledb'
When I use Postman to send a POST to http://localhost:3000/api/signup  I get an error withj oracledb, however I am using PostgreSQL, not Oracle...
○ Compiling /api/signup ...
 ⨯ ./node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/oracledb/index.js:44:1
Module not found: Can't resolve 'oracledb'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/index.js
./node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/internal/config-resolver.js
./node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/Knex.js
./node_modules/knex/lib/index.js
./node_modules/knex/knex.js
./connect-connector.ts
./app/api/signup/route.ts
 ⨯ ./node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/oracledb/index.js:44:1
Module not found: Can't resolve 'oracledb'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/index.js
./node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/internal/config-resolver.js
./node_modules/knex/lib/knex-builder/Knex.js
./node_modules/knex/lib/index.js
./node_modules/knex/knex.js
./connect-connector.ts
./app/api/signup/route.ts


So, I have just encountered the same issue you are experiencing and just had it resolve right now. You can read it at https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/52091#issuecomment-1623722996 but to keep it short, you need to add a config in your next.fongi.js|.mjs since it looks like knex is not yet 100% supported.
Here's an example of the change:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    experimental: {
        serverComponentsExternalPackages: ['knex']
    },
};

export default nextConfig;

Good luck and happy coding!
